# NodeJS as javascript server pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

What setup should i use to have a bunch of HTML (*.html) files - some of them having server side code (`<?= 'Hello world'?>`) - acting as javascript server pages on a node.js server?

Comment: Did you try using Express? It allows you to have separate directories for pages that you can render on the server and those that have static HTML data.

Comment: Yes I'm using Express. The thing is I'm building on top of a preexisting static html site. I'd like to add some server side processing using Node/Express as a server pages language in those files.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using express, but aren't aware of server side templating options available, why don't you give the ExpressWorks tutorial a go!

https://github.com/azat-co/expressworks

It provides very simple instructions on installation and setup, and introduces a templating engine called `Jade`. I believe this is one valid option that can handle what you're looking for.